# how to configure tomcat 5.5 to change localhost to ip address

Tags: tomcat

I run an application on http://localhost:8080 but I want to use my machine IP address or an alias instead of localhost to put my application on Internet.
Please tell me how can I do this.

Please help me....

Comment: If you have public ip address and no firewall (hopefully you have it) just try to go to e.g. whatismyip.com and then type in this ip address. Also you might find helpful http://www.noip.com/.

Answer (score 1):

Go to Tomcat `conf` directory and open `server.xml`

Find

```
<Host name="localhost" appBase="webapps" unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true">
```

And replace by (12.34.56.78 being your public ip-address)

```
<Host name="12.34.56.78" appBase="webapps" unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true">
```

See JiriS's comment about how to find your public ip-address.

Restart Tomcat.

If you do have a firewall you need to forward port 8080 (or port 80 if you prefer) to your local machine at port 8080 where Tomcat is running.

Test if it works by going to someone else's house and open a browser

```
http://12.34.56.78:8080/examples
```

Which will show you the examples from the tomcat/webapps directory.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know anything about tomcat, but if you're using Windows, you can edit the hosts file to redirect localhost to an IP address.

To do this:

1. Press Windows key + R
2. Type `notepad.exe`
3. Go to File > Open
4. Open this file
   `C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts`
5. Put the name and IP address you want your website to go with this format: `IP alias`
6. Save

Example of correct hosts file:

```
12.345.678.90 www.example.com
```

[More about editing hosts file](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/27350/beginner-geek-how-to-edit-your-hosts-file/)

**Note:** Actually you could just access your localhost with 127.0.0.1 like `http://127.0.0.1:8080`